# Loop inside the function can't run as well as an outside loop

Tags: python, list, loops

I tried to find all the duplicates in list by the loop like the following

```
num = [1, 2, 2, 1]

for i in range(1, len(num)):
if num[i] == num[i - 1]:
    print(num[i])
```

and it return all the duplicates inside the list but when i pass that inside the the function it only pick the first like the following

```
def FindDuplicates(nums):
nums.sort()
for i in range(1, len(nums)):
    if nums[i] == nums[i - 1]:
        return nums[i]
```

and this function remove the duplicates but can't work well as i expected
means when list looks like this `print(RemoveDuplicate([1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5, 6]))`
it work well but this `print(RemoveDuplicate([1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5, 6, 6, 6]))`
the function crush

```
def RemoveDuplicate(array):
no_double = []
its_index = 0
founded = 0
for arr in array:
    if array.count(arr) > 1:
        founded = arr
        its_index = array.index(arr)
    elif array.count(arr) <= 1:
        no_double.append(arr)
no_double.insert(its_index, founded)
return no_double
```

when there is a lot of duplicates this function can't pick them all out
any one who can help me to fix this bug

Comment: Think: what is the type of the object that you are returning? Answer: it's an `int`. But it sounds like you want a `List[int]`.

Comment: You can eliminate a lot of problems by checking your types. (And creating simple functions, as you've done here.)

Comment: how @Mateen Ulhaq

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can anyone help me to fix this bug?

Doing it your way, maybe this:

```
def FindDuplicates(nums):
    d = []
    nums.sort()
    for i in range(1, len(nums)):
        if nums[i] == nums[i - 1]:
            d.append(nums[i])
    return d
```

The reason yours don't work is because when the program reaches a return statement in a function, it will jump out of the function right then and there. So if you want to returns multiple values in a single function, make sure they're returned all at once.

Answer (score 2):

Try this :)

```
from collections import Counter


lst = [4,3,2,4,5,6,4,7,6,8]
d =  Counter(lst)  # -> Counter({4: 3, 6: 2, 3: 1, 2: 1, 5: 1, 7: 1, 8: 1})
res = [k for k, v in d.items() if v > 1]
print(res)
```